# I started the zookeeper log and reported an error

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I'm working with zookeeper, 3.6.1
My computer is Mac, and I installed zookeeper with brew tool, but I failed with the command zkserver start. I used jps -l to view the process and found the process of zookeeper.

Then I went on to look at the log file that zookeeper started. An error was found.

```
2020-11-18 15:48:28 ContextHandler [WARN] Empty contextPath
2020-11-18 15:48:29 ServerCnxnFactory [WARN] maxCnxns is not configured, using default value 0.
2020-11-18 15:48:29 NIOServerCnxnFactory [ERROR] Thread Thread[main,5,main] died
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.nio.ByteBuffer.clear()Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;
        at org.apache.jute.BinaryOutputArchive.stringToByteBuffer(BinaryOutputArchive.java:80)
        at org.apache.jute.BinaryOutputArchive.writeString(BinaryOutputArchive.java:110)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.data.Id.serialize(Id.java:51)
        at org.apache.jute.BinaryOutputArchive.writeRecord(BinaryOutputArchive.java:126)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.data.ACL.serialize(ACL.java:52)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ReferenceCountedACLCache.serialize(ReferenceCountedACLCache.java:152)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.DataTree.serializeAcls(DataTree.java:1359)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.DataTree.serialize(DataTree.java:1372)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.util.SerializeUtils.serializeSnapshot(SerializeUtils.java:171)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.FileSnap.serialize(FileSnap.java:227)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.FileSnap.serialize(FileSnap.java:246)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.FileTxnSnapLog.save(FileTxnSnapLog.java:472)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.FileTxnSnapLog.restore(FileTxnSnapLog.java:291)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZKDatabase.loadDataBase(ZKDatabase.java:285)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer.loadData(ZooKeeperServer.java:484)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer.startdata(ZooKeeperServer.java:655)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory.startup(NIOServerCnxnFactory.java:758)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ServerCnxnFactory.startup(ServerCnxnFactory.java:130)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServerMain.runFromConfig(ZooKeeperServerMain.java:159)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServerMain.initializeAndRun(ZooKeeperServerMain.java:112)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServerMain.main(ZooKeeperServerMain.java:67)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.initializeAndRun(QuorumPeerMain.java:140)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.main(QuorumPeerMain.java:90)
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it's about brew install.
Try another installation method